# How to enter a pod as root?

Tags: linux, kubernetes

Currently I enter the pod as a mysql user using the command:

`kubectl exec -it PODNAME -n NAMESPACE bash`

I want to enter a container as root.
I've tried the following command:

`kubectl exec -it PODNAME -n NAMESPACE -u root ID /bin/bash`

`kubectl exec -it PODNAME -n NAMESPACE -u root ID bash`

There must be a way.
:-)

Comment: I found the answer. You cannot log into the pod directly as root via kubectl.  You can find out what node the pod is running, then find out its image id and log into the node. you then have to exec in via docker: `sudo docker exec -it -u root [DOCKER ID] /bin/bash`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer.

You cannot log into the pod directly as root via kubectl.

You can do via the following steps.

1. find out what node it is running on `kubectl get pod -n [NAMESPACE] -o wide`
2. ssh node
3. find the docker container `sudo docker ps | grep [namespace]`
4. log into container as root `sudo docker exec -it -u root [DOCKER ID] /bin/bash`

Comment: Actually there is absolutely no difference between doing `kubectl exec` and `docker exec`. This is just more work.

Comment: no @suren, if there are multiple docker in pod, it will definitely different.

Comment: no it's not. You just pass `-c` to say to which container you want to access.

Comment: It is absolutely different. You can't specify `-u root` in the kubectl command

Comment: how to 2) ssh node

Comment: @Ilya it depends on where your node is running. If you are running them on a cloud cluster, there should be a compute instance available to ssh (https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) that is hosting the k8s agent, if you are running on KinD then you can just `docker exec -it [NAME_OF_K8S_NODE_CONTAINER] /bin/bash`.

Comment: Also remember, Docker is deprecated after Kubernetes v1.20. So step 3 may be `crictl ps -label io.kubernetes.pod.namespace=[NAMESPACE]` but step 4 requires the `-u` option which isn't supported by the CRI API currently https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/issues/507.

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is already a possibility to connect via kubectl addon  [kubectl-plugins](https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins). Found a solution replying onto related question.

```
git clone https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins.git
cd kubectl-plugins
./install-plugins.sh
source ~/.bash_profile
kubectl ssh -u root suse

Connecting...
Pod: suse
Namespace: NONE
User: root
Container: NONE
Command: /bin/sh

If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
sh-5.0#
```

Comment: This was the more useful answer for me. It doesn't require that you have SSH access into the kubernetes nodes -- you only need to be able to create another pod in the same namespace.

Comment: This command fails for me:
Connecting...
Pod: details-v1-6448f9bdc8-qlvv2
Namespace: NONE
User: root
Container: NONE
Command: /bin/sh

If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
pod cluster1-tenanta-ns/ssh-pod-11797 terminated (Error)

Answer (score 0):

SSH as root to kubernates pod.
For those on Windows Platform using minikube.
First you to ssh inside minikube

```
minikube ssh --user root
```

Then you need to find desired docker container

```
docker ps | grep NAME_POD
```

Copy fully qualified docker container name then use docker exec:

```
sudo docker exec -it -u root FQDN_CONTAINER bash
```

In my case it was :

```
sudo docker exec -it -u root k8s_jupyter_my-jupyter-0_default
_f05e2913-f1fd-4084-a8e8-e783519d4a71_0 bash
```

Once then i had full root access in bash inside POD.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the scenarios and found out that in case of minkube running kubernetes cluster you will get root shell. So the below command will give root shell for minikube.

```
kubectl exec -it podname -c containerid -- /bin/bash
```

For without minikube you will have to use docker exec with "-u root" tag:

```
docker exec -it -u root containerid bash
```

The above command will give you root shell.

Check below image where "whoami" give root output.
[image]