# Is there any way to get stacktrace of process inside pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gdb, suse

I am trying to get stacktrace of my process which is running inside pod of k8s. For that I have installed gstack binary into it, but it does not give me any output.

Here is the sample demo:

```
sh-4.3# gstack
Usage: gstack <process-id>
sh-4.3# sleep 100 &
[2] 1594
sh-4.3# gstack 1594
sh-4.3# gstack 1594 > test
sh-4.3# cat test
sh-4.3#
```

Can someone help me on it?

PS: It is fine if you have other way to gather stack trace (other then gstack) too.

Comment: What is the process you want to check stack traces on?

Comment: Any process, let's say sleep command right now, sleep 100.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect to pod as root to view traces.

Used latest [opensuse/tumbleweed](https://hub.docker.com/r/opensuse/tumbleweed) for example pod

```
#suse-pod.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: suse
spec:
  containers:
  - name: suse
    image: opensuse/tumbleweed
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "tail -f /dev/null" ]
```

Connected  to pod in regular way and start the process

```
suse:/ # kubectl exec suse -ti -- bash
suse:/ # sleep 100000&
[1] 677


suse:/ # ps aux | grep sleep
root         677  0.0  0.0   2324   764 pts/3    S    14:16   0:00 sleep 100000
```

Check:

`suse:/ # gstack 677 --> empty`

```
suse:/ # gdb
(gdb) attach 677
Attaching to process 677
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
```

ptrace: Operation not permitted. <-- this is root cause

What you can do:

1) you can(as I did) install 3rd party awesome [kubectl-plugins](https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins) and use `kubectl ssh -u root [pod]` to access pod under root.

```
git clone https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins.git
cd kubectl-plugins
./install-plugins.sh
source ~/.bash_profile
kubectl ssh -u root suse

Connecting...
Pod: suse
Namespace: NONE
User: root
Container: NONE
Command: /bin/sh

If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
sh-5.0# gstack 677
#0  0x00007f8eeb2a7603 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000055fd4fc88677 in ?? ()
#2  0x000055fd4fc88450 in ?? ()
#3  0x000055fd4fc85500 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f8eeb201e0b in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x000055fd4fc855da in ?? ()


sh-5.0# gdb       
GNU gdb (GDB; openSUSE Tumbleweed) 8.3.1
(gdb) attach 677
Attaching to process 677
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/sleep...
(No debugging symbols found in /usr/bin/sleep)
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib64/libc.so.6)
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
0x00007f8eeb2a7603 in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: zypper install coreutils-debuginfo-8.31-2.2.x86_64
```

2) You can follow @mac [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043159/how-to-enter-a-pod-as-root)

> -find out what node it is running on kubectl get po -n [NAMESPACE] -o wide
>
> -ssh node
>
> -find the docker container sudo docker ps | grep [namespace]
>
> -log into container as root sudo docker exec -it -u root [DOCKER ID] /bin/bash

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @VKR, thanks for your efforts, I have also tried with root user with given plugin, but it still gives me permission denied error, please help me if you have other approach.

Comment: describe your exact configuration, what image are you using? It would be easy to help knowing all the details, steps you already performed and logs

Comment: I am using debian:8.7  os inside pods, and I can not access node on which that pod is running in our environment, and I want to get stack trace like you did for sleep command.

Comment: just reproduced  with kubectl plugins + debian jessie - result is the same for me. I can attach to process and see all the traces. Probably you have to provide in question all you  steps with output.

Comment: I can not give you entire dockerfile, but how you installed gdb? I have installed it using this command: "zypper install gdb"

Comment: http://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial/how-install-gdb
`apt-get update && apt-get install gdb`

Comment: I think container has podsecuritypolicy applied, so I can not access it, is this plugin allow it?

Comment: yes, that can be a root cause, but I havent mentioned that since you dais nothing about `podsecuritypolicy` from the beginning. And no, plugin wont help in this situation